# Spring Boot logs not visible in minikube

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, kubernetes, minikube

I've set up a simple **Spring Boot** application without any custom logging, so **everything gets logged to the console**.

This works fine when running it from my IDE.

The second thing is, that I wrapped this application, as a jar in a docker image. This image / container will simply run the jar with `java -jar` - and yet again, when running this Docker container locally, **I can see all the Spring Boot logs in the docker container logs**.

But for some reason, when I load this image in minikube, and when I start the deployment, service, and pod - **the Spring Boot logs are missing in the pod / container logs**.

Eg when I run

```
kubectl logs pod-name --all-containers
```

**I see the container logs, but they do not contain Spring Boot logs**.

I run the jar file within the Dockerfile like so:

```
CMD java $JAVA_ARGS -jar $TARGET_JAR_FILE
```

Any ideas what could be wrong? How do I get Spring Boot logs to be visible on minikube pod / container?

Answer (score 0):

"With some troubleshooting, I see that the pod displays the container logs," - what exactly do you mean here? To see container logs in minikube/ kubernetes you always have to run `kubectl logs pod-name`, If the pod is formed from more than one container, you must also specify the name of the container you want to inspect: `kubectl logs pod-name container-name` or just set the `--all-containers` flag to include log lines produced by any of the containers in the Pod. Please specify which commands you have used.

Comment: Question updated with some clarification.